# AngularJS Datatables with display length but without pagination

Tags: angularjs, datatable, pagination, angular-datatables

I'm working with [angular-datatables](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/).

My end goal is to have a table with no pagination but with a "link" that allow to "show 25 more entries" (and without using the select length "10", "25", "50","100" etc).

So first of all, I set the display length to 25 with :

```
this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withBootstrap()
    .withDisplayLength(25)
```

Great my table is showing only 25 five entries with pagination.
No I try to disable the pagination with :

```
this.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
   .withBootstrap()
   .withDisplayLength(25)
   .withOption('paging', false)
```

And then the pagination is disable but the table is showing more than 25 entries.
I get that it's kind of logic since otherwise there will be no means to acces those 25+ entries but that's what i'd liked to acheive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply hide the injected pagination element when the table is finished rendering :

```
.withOption('drawCallback', function() {
   $('.dataTables_paginate').hide()
})
```

`.dataTables_paginate` is the overall `<div>` where dataTables places the pagination control, if any.

Comment: I didn't think of the simpliest solution ! In the same principe I just hide in the css the .dataTables_paginate